# Created hook not running again when pushing the same route with a new query

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a component with a created hook like this:

```js
created() {
    if (this.$route.query.q) {
        //fetchdata
    }
}
```

However within the same component I try doing `` $router.push(`?q=${search}`) `` and the URL changes but the created hook doesn't rerun.

Comment: try $route.replace

Comment: You need to bind a key to your `router-link` tag and update that every time you want to re-render the current component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vue will reuse the component if you re-route to it, so `created` won't run again.  You can force it to do so with a key on the `<router-view>`:

```html
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath" />
```

or use the `beforeRouteUpdate` hook:

```js
beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
  if (this.$route.query.q) {
    //fetchdata
  }
  next();
}
```

This hook won't run when the component is first created, so with this solution you may need to use both `created` and `beforeRouteUpdate`.

**Some differences:**

With the key solution, the component won't be cached so it will be recreated on each route (which is what causes `created` to run each time).  Maybe you wouldn't want that if you needed to do something only once in created such as calling an api only once regardless of the query. Or in rare cases maybe there would be a performance implication to recreating (probably not).

With `beforeRouteUpdate` you may have to use the same logic in 2 lifecycle hooks, but that's not really a problem. You can also reroute from this hook, which might be useful.

Use whichever one you prefer / makes more sense, as long as you understand the differences.